# Views related nodes with contextual filters multiple-value handling problem

Tags: 7, views

I created a [related nodes block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3?answertab=votes#tab-top) with views.

Everything seems good but there is one problem that I couldn't find a solution for days.

The views has **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)** as contextual filter.

If a node has only one taxonomy term there is no problem and the related views block shows the related nodes tagged with the same taxonomy term.

But if a node has multiple taxonomy terms, the related nodes block shows all the nodes that are tagged with **any** of the taxonomy terms although I selected the **Filter to items that share all terms** option.

[image: Multiple-value handling]

**Is there any way to solve this problem?**

Comment: Great stuff here. I imagine a lot of people will miss this option. Why this option is hidden under More and not in the main arguments section is baffling to me. Thanks mate. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was very simple but I missed it, you don't miss it if you are in the same situation:

Tick the **Allow multiple values** below the **MORE** part in contextual filter.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, this is so easy once you know how and so not obvious until you know...