# Only the first result shows in my view

Tags: 7, views, theming, database

I have a view with 2 fields, `node_title` and `node_related_content`. For the field `node_related_content` I use the `formatter = rendered node` and `view mode = Preview`. These *rendered nodes* are fetched from a multiple value field in a content type "product group" that I use for listing related products.

In the view I use a contextual filter that gives me all the node IDs that belong to this view.

Now, the view works fine for one result (one group of rendered nodes). But if I enter more than one node ID in the preview field it onlyt gives me the first group... I need to have all the products groups, not just the first one.

What do I do wrong here?

This is the resulting SQL query:

> SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid,
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare.delta AS
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare_delta,
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare.language AS
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare_language,
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare.bundle AS
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare_bundle,
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare.field_koppla_givare_nid AS
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare_field_koppla_givare_nid, 'node' AS
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare_node_entity_type FROM  {node} node LEFT
>   JOIN {field_data_field_koppla_givare} field_data_field_koppla_givare
>   ON node.nid = field_data_field_koppla_givare.entity_id AND
>   field_data_field_koppla_givare.entity_type = 'node' WHERE (( (node.nid
>   = '26262,21888' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') )))

So the above query only shows the rendered nodes found in the product group 26262. The product group 21888 is ignored.

UPDATE: after experimenting with the SQL query in phpmyadmin I have found out that the last row in the query should look like this:

> WHERE (( (node.nid IN('26262', '21888', '21877') ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') )))

Now, how can I alter my view to reflect that change?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple, and I found it here: [Views related nodes with contextual filters multiple-value handling problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138434/views-related-nodes-with-contextual-filters-multiple-value-handling-problem)

I just had to tick the "Allow multiple values" box under the More section in the contextual filter. A bit embarassing in the end... but that box was very well hidden indeed.